# Move and resize a Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.resizable(width = True, height = True)

class App(Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.pack()
    root.geometry('605x396+340+150')


window = App(master = root)
window.mainloop()
```

I'm on Python 2.7.10 on Mac OS.
First of all I didn't find any instruction to let my window be movable.
Second I insert the resizable instruction but the window don't let me resize it.

Comment: `.overrideredirect(1)` disables all of the OS/window manager features for resizing or moving the window.  The Tk root is resizable by default without having to call `.resizable()`, but you've explicitly turned off the ability to use that feature.

Comment: Thanks!!! There is a way to hide the default title bar without the command overrideredirect?

Comment: No, you cannot hide the title bar any way except with `overrideredirect`. If you use that, you will have to create your own bindings for moving and resizing the window.

Comment: Add some context to how you want your window to move. Do you want to to have some kind of border you can click on or do  you want to be able to just drag the window around from anywhere on it?

Comment: I just would like to drag my window and resize it, but I want also to hide the title bar, so I've to decide one of the two.
I think I prefer to hide the title bar